# Grunt 'Build' error

Tags: gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I am not getting enough solutions for the error I am getting in when do `grunt build`
this is the error.

```
   Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
>>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.module.exports (/home/user/projects/misc/lfc-dev/project/Gruntfile.js:13:3)
>>     at loadTask (/home/user/projects/misc/lfc-dev/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:325:10)
>>     at Task.task.init (/home/user/projects/misc/lfc-dev/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:437:5)
>>     at Object.grunt.tasks (/home/user/projects/misc/lfc-dev/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:120:8)
>>     at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/home/user/projects/misc/lfc-dev/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)

Running tasks: build
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried,
npm install,
npm install grunt,
npm install grunt-cli

^^ these are installed globally as well. Nothing Helped me so far.

Answer (score 1):

The log says `Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'`. You are missing `load-grunt-tasks`. Perhapse it is not included in packages.json

Try

```
npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks
```

Also make sure that `npm install` wasn't interrupted before. If so, try removing the `node_modules` directory then tryn `npm install` again.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad,
Fixed it by running npm install with sudo :)

Comment: I was going to suggest that at the beginning too. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am using linux and it requesting to run the command as sudo.
And then boom... worked fine.